# Can't authenticate user in Dreamweaver for a Log in Page

Tags: php, html, css, dreamweaver

I'm trying to Server Behaviours->User Authentication->Log in User in Dreamweaver for my Login.php page (see below) and I can't as I get the message that Log in Form must have at least one element of the form that gets a value of the username or password. It says I should add this element but... I have it already in my code...?

```
  <?php require_once('Connections/c1.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_c1, $c1);
$query_Login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Login = mysql_query($query_Login, $c1) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Login = mysql_fetch_assoc($Login);
$totalRows_Login = mysql_num_rows($Login);mysql_select_db($database_c1, $c1);
$query_Login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Login = mysql_query($query_Login, $c1) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Login = mysql_fetch_assoc($Login);
$totalRows_Login = mysql_num_rows($Login);
$query_Login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Login = mysql_query($query_Login, $c1) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Login = mysql_fetch_assoc($Login);
$totalRows_Login = mysql_num_rows($Login);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="x-Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="x-Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dokument bez tytułu</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Holder">
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="NavBar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Login</li>
            <li><a href="#">Register</li>
            <li><a href="#">Forgot Password</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="Content">
    <div id="PageHeading">
      <h1>Technical University of Lodz</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="ContentLeft">
      <h2>Please, log in</h2>
      <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="ContentRight">
      <form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="POST" action="">
      <table width="400" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><h6>
              <label for="textarea">Username:</label>
              <br>
              <br>
              <textarea name="UserName" class="StyleTxtField" id="UserName"></textarea>
            </h6></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><h6>
              <label for="textarea">Password:<br>
                <br>
              </label>
              <textarea name="Password" class="StyleTxtField" id="Password"></textarea>
            </h6></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="LoginButton" value="Login"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Login);
?>
```

Comment: 1. Also, out of curiosity, is there a reason you're not using the "action=" part of the form and doing it all inline?
2. mysql_free_result() is deprecated as of PHP 5, which makes me wonder which version of PHP you're using. If you're using PHP7, you should go with an alternative, such as one of those described at the top of this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php

Answer (score 0):

Below is an excerpt from Adobe's Dreamweaver How-to page for creating login pages. If you didn't follow step 2 correctly, this may be your issue, though it's hard to exactly pinpoint where the problem arose without knowing just where in the process of adding the Log In User behavior it gave you your error message. Give the link below a read-through, though, and hopefully it will get you on the right track.

> 1. In the Server Behaviors panel (Window > Server Behaviors), click the Plus (+) button and select User Authentication > Log In User from the pop‑up menu.
> 2. Specify the form and the form objects that visitors use to enter their user name and password.
>
> source: https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/building-login-page.html#verify_the_user_name_and_password